# Too much time at load web view in view pager

Tags: java, android, memory, webview, android-viewpager

I have to use view pager for display 200 HTML data into  web-view in single activity but it takes high memory so every time crash in device

How can I fix it?

Comment: what do you mean by 200 html data? like 200 html webpages into single activity?

Comment: Can you post your activity code?

Comment: Please edit your question to add [**sample data**](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. 
Provide them as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and strictly [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). 
**DO NOT** post code or additional information in comments. 
Please ensure you have a [**minimal, complete and verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Make viewPager to load two pages at the moment .The one that is displayed and the next one.
Try using this code:
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)